# Is there a program to rip multiple CDs to mp3 and then burn them onto a single CD?

Tags: audio, burning, ripping, audio-recording

What free software will allow me to rip a song or two off of a CD, then insert another CD to rip another song or two, until I have enough to fill a blank CD.

I would also like it to burn the blank CD.

Comment: windows...linux...bsd...mac?

Answer (score 0):

Audiograbber it's freeware now, became freeware couple years ago:
http://www.audiograbber.org/download.html